# What does 「ちんちんかいかい」 mean?

Tags: translation, words

Context: Bottom right panel.

[image]

> はーいちんちんかいかい

I think it's a made up word because I could not find it's meaning when I searched for it online. It seems like an onomatopoeia.

The only thing that comes close is an [article](https://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/hl?a=20190722-00000066-dal-spo) about a Japanese basketball player who entered the NBA

Answer (score 23):

ちんちんかく means 正座をする(sitting straight) in Toyama dialect. However you had better not use it except in Toyama prefecture, because most Japanese people would think it means "to scratch a penis".

Comment: Thank you! Is かいかい also a part of Toyama dialect ?

Comment: I think かいかい itself is not a Toyama dialect.

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted me; @Yuuichi Tam the fact that I have lived only ca 4 years in Toyama doesn't make me an expert (esp in the manga circles, which are very distant to me) so I was surprised by your answer, and, in addition, surprised if a manga would use such a minor dialect; therefore I vote you down [I will compensate if we meet at Pot Still ;-) ]

Comment: @Tuomo I don't know Toyama dialect at all, but it seems to mean it and is appropriate from the context. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%E3%81%A1%E3%82%93%E3%81%A1%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F

Comment: I don't disagree with your translation, so in that sense maybe downvoting was inappropriate, while I am interested in knowing why you [without knowing the Toyama dialect] assumed that was the case. Could it be that the scene just happened in Toyama [which thanks to getting the Shinkansen has flourished], but, as mentioned, if you want to sell manga you would probably not use Toyama dialect, although I am not in the manga scene. [ p.s. So, no Pot Still Guiness for your ;-(]

Answer (score 2):

It's not a made up word.

"Oh yeah, sit! cute!"

ちんちん is dog sitting and giving a paw to the owner.

http://madamaniau-inunoshitsuke.com/111/142/000711.php

かいかい is abbreviation of "かわいい　かわいい"

Comment: Thank you! Any source on `かいかい is abbreviation of "かわいい　かわいい"` ?

Comment: Dog is not giving its paw to the owner in the image

Answer (score -2):

You're fluent in Japanese and read the Tale of Genji out loud to your dog, but you don't know the everyday meaning of チン unless you've lived in Japan in the same house with Japanese people who, if not family, nevertheless treat you like family.
Chin is a transient verb taking the standard +suru pattern. The phrase you'd be hearing would, in many cases, be a request: チンして chin it (for me, please). Chin was taken from the ringing sound of a bicycle bell. Noting how that particular sound slices through city noise, developers of microwave ovens for the consumer market modeled the "done" chime on this チン noise when they got around to addressing the complaints of users who had forgotten about things in the 電子レンジ microwave oven because it was silent as a dumbwaiter. To chin is to warm something up in the microwave.

Comment: つまり、質問のマンガのセリフ 「はーい ちんちんかいかい」の「ちん」は、「電子レンジでチンする」という意味の「チン」だ、というのが回答ですか？

Answer (score -4):

> Chin Touch (with a hold)
>   A chin touch means your dog moves the bottom of his muzzle (his chin) to the palm of your upward facing hand and holds it there. ... After a couple of repetitions of doing this correctly, add the command word “chin” before the dog moves his chin onto your hand. Aug 17, 2018
>   [Akc pet insurance](https://www.akcpetinsurance.com/blog/teach-your-dog-shake-chin-touch-crawling)

Answer (score -5):

A direct translation is "that's right, please scratch my penis"

We all know what "ちんちん" means (maybe) but "かいかい" means to scratch or "please scratch".

Now you know....is what I'd like to say but Japanese has a lot of words like this that could come off wrong.
Whilst it sounds like that, what he was trying to say is "yes , sit, cute" something along those lines.

It's a kinda pun

Now you really know.

Edit:

Ok so I asked my wife and from what I heard he is actually yelling the dog to scratch it's penis so yeh. Apparently is something like a performance for a dog to do as people find it funny.

These are the exact words from her and she is Japanese so yeh....

Comment: `I asked my wife... she is Japanese` <-- Will you show her these pages... [「ちんちんかいかい」富山県あたりの方言で「正座」という意味だそうです。(2007/12/07)](http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1197025958)　・　[「ちんちんかく」が標準語の「正座する」にあたり、「ちんちんかいかい」は「座ってください」との意味だという](https://news.merumo.ne.jp/article/genre/8849558)　・　[ちんちんかいかい は #富山 を代表する方言。 #おちんちんかく で #おちんちん は #鎮座 #正座 「あぐらをかく」の「かく」](https://twitter.com/nabeana/status/1153478068083650561)